# Bibliography style vancouver

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to use bibliography style vancouver to write my thesis. When I use `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}` it shows error. I am using overleaf. Is there anyone using vancouver style?
Thanks.

Comment: Use plainnat instead. Vancouver just means numbered.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}` works on Overleaf anyway; so if you're getting an error, there may be something else that's gone wrong in your code. The error message will give you hints about what's wrong.

Comment: What error does it show? What did you try? What does your document look like? Please consider showing us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), a small example document that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks @ Johannes_B. But it does not show the bibliography list alphabetically. It shows the order used in my text. I want the bibliography list alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

"It shows the order used in my text." is the [default behaviour of the Vancouver system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver_system#Labelling_citations) rather than an error. Instead of `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}`, use e.g. `\bibliographystyle{plain}` that is a numbered and alphabetically sorted citation style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!